# How to find subset of a Google maps route?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geospatial

The following is my scenario:

**John** is travelling from *Mumbai* to *Coimbatore*. **Joe** is travelling from *Mumbai* to place *Bangalore*, the place *Bangalore* is located in the **John**'s travel route.

- Is there any Google maps api to find out a route is a subset of another route?
- Or, Is there a way to find out *Bangalore* is lying on the *Mumbai* to *Coimbatore* route's nearby (by some kms, ex., 5 kms away)?

**What i have tried?**

> Found a overview polyline encoded route of *Mumbai* to *Coimbatore* , from this encoded route i can able to find the array of longitudes,latitudes. And same way found a *Mumbai* to *Bangalore* encoded route.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the overlap of polylines in order to draw the common segment as shaded on google maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230611/how-to-find-the-overlap-of-polylines-in-order-to-draw-the-common-segment-as-shad)

Answer (score 0):

After googling, i found couple of links, that solves my problem.

- [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452385/finding-particular-cities-along-your-path)
- [another stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783685/islocationonedge-tolerance-calculation-in-terms-of-km/)
- [google developers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#isLocationOnEdge)

isLocationOnEdge() is a function in Geometry library solves the issue.

**from the google developer documentation**:

> **isLocationOnEdge()** is, To determine whether a point falls on or near a polyline, or on or near the edge of a polygon